# What would a "moral" proof of the Weil Conjectures require?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, motives, weil-conjectures

At the very end of [this 2006 interview (rm)](http://www2.u-bourgogne.fr/monge/g.dito/poisson2006/ram_interview/poisson2006_Maxim_interview.ram), Kontsevich says

> "...many great theorems are originally proven but I think the proofs are not, kind of, "morally right." There should be better proofs...I think the Index Theorem by Atiyah and Singer...its original proof, I think it's ugly in a sense and up to now, we don't have "the right proof." Or Deligne's proof of the Weil conjectures, it's a morally wrong proof. There are three proofs now, but still not the right one."

I'm trying to understand what Kontsevich means by a proof not being "morally right." I've read [this article by Eugenia Cheng](http://www.cheng.staff.shef.ac.uk/morality/morality.pdf) on morality in the context of mathematics, but I'm not completely clear on what it means with respect to an explicit example. The general idea seems to be that a "moral proof" would be one that is well-motivated by the theory and in which each step is justified by a guiding principle, as opposed to an "immoral" one that is mathematically correct but relatively ad hoc.

To narrow the scope of this question and (hopefully) make it easier to understand for myself, I would like to focus on the second part of the comment. Why would Kontsevich says that Deligne's proof is not "morally right"? More importantly, **what would a "moral proof" of the Weil Conjectures entail?**

Would a morally proof have to use motivic ideas, like Grothendieck hoped for in his attempts at proving the Weil Conjectures? Have there been any attempts at "moralizing" Deligne's proof? How do do the other proofs of the Weil Conjectures measure up with respect to mathematical morality?

Comment: Somebody mentioned that "Grothendieck objected to Deligne's argument" - the topic is mentioned in passing by Pierre Cartier, and he says that Grothendieck felt "betrayed":
http://xahlee.info/math/i/Alexander_Grothendieck_cartier.pdf

Answer (score 51):

I would guess that Grothendieck's envisaged proof, via the standard conjectures, would be "morally right" in Kontsevich's sense.  (Although there is the question of how the standard
conjectures would be proved; since they remain conjectures, this question is open for now!)

The objection to Deligne's proof is that it relies on various techniques (passing to symmetric powers and Rankin--Selberg inspired ideas, analytic arguments related to the positivity of the coefficients of the zeta-function, and other such things) that don't seem to be naturally related to the question at hand.  I believe that Grothendieck had a similar objection to
Deligne's argment.

As a number-theorist, I think Deligne's proof is fantastic.  One of the appeals (at least to me) of number theory is that none of the proofs are "morally right" in Kontsevich's sense.  Obviously, this is a very personal feeling.

(Of course, a proof of the standard conjectures --- any proof, to my mind --- would also be fantastic!)

[Edit, for clarification; this is purely an aside, though:] Some arguments in number theory, for example the primitive root theorem discussed in the comments, are pure algebra when viewed appropriately, and here there are very natural and direct arguments.  (For example,
in the case of primitive roots, there is basic field theory combined with Hensel's lemma/Newton approximation; this style of argument extends, in some form, to the very general setting of complete local rings.)  When I wrote that none of the proof in number theory are "morally right", I had in mind largely the proofs in modern algebraic number theory, such as the modularity of elliptic curves, Serre's conjecture, Sato--Tate,
and so on.  The proofs use (almost) everything under the sun, and follow no dogma.  Tate wrote of abelian class field theory that "it is true because it could not be otherwise"
(if I remember the quote correctly), which I took to mean (given the context) that the proofs in the end are unenlightening as to the real reason it is true; they are simply logically correct proofs.  This seems to be even more the case with the proofs of results in non-abelian class field theory such as those mentioned above.  Despite this, I personally find the arguments wonderful; it is one of the appeals of the subject for me.

Comment: In that theorem, "the only cyclic groups" should be "the only units groups mod m" and p should be an odd prime. There are two parts to this theorem: (1) units mod m are not cyclic for other m and (2) units mod m are cyclic for those m.  It's easier to show (1). If m is any other number then the units mod m have more than one element of order 2: if m is divisible by 4 and is not 4 itself, then -1 and 1+m/2 mod m both have order 2 and are different.  If m is twice an odd number, units mod m and mod m/2 are isomorphic, so we can focus on odd m. 

Comment: What problem do you have with the standard proofs?

Comment: If m is not an odd prime power then we can write m = ab where a > 2 and b > 2, so (Z/m)* = (Z/a)* x (Z/b)*, so visibly there are a few elements of order 2: (-1,1), (1,-1), and (-1,-1).  That completes a morally right proof of item (1).  

Comment: As for item (2), that when m is 2, 4, p^k, or 2p^k for odd prime p, the units mod m are cyclic, we can reduce easily to the case of p^k.  In this case I'd use p-adics:  

(Z/p^k)* = (Z_p/p^kZ_p)* = Z_p*/(1 + p^kZ_p) 
                         = (mu_{p-1} x (1+pZ_p))/(1+p^kZ_p) 
                         = mu_{p-1} x (1+pZ_p)/(1+p^kZ_p).
Since mu_{p-1} is cyclic of order p - 1 and 1+p is a generator of the second factor, a group of p-power order, we've written (Z/p^k)* as a product of cyclic groups of relatively prime order, so the group itself is cyclic. QED

Comment: Who needs 6 different cases?!?

Comment: I'll wrap this up by saying the usual proofs (as in Ireland-Rosen?) are clunky on the existence side (that the m's which work really work) because they can't bring in p-adics and therefore lose the flexibility of writing the multiplicative group (Z/p^k)* as a genuine quotient of multiplicative groups, namely Z_p*/(1+p^kZ_p).

Comment: The only if part is dealt with by Keith Conrad's comment. For the if part: the existence of a primitive root mod p is algebra (any finite multiplicative subgroup of a field is cyclic). To get from mod $p$ to mod $p^n$, one uses Hensel's lemma (or, if you prefer, Newton approximation); of course, you can also be very explicit and just observe directly via the binomial theorem that 1 + p, or 1 + 4 when p = 2, generate the units mod p^n that are 1 mod p (or 1 mod 4 when p = 2). Hensel/Newton is the basic tool for deforming over nilpotent ideals, and I think is "morally right" in that context.

Comment: My comments were less important, so they're not worth reposting.

Comment: The other thing worth noting about this proof is that, when applied to prime-power ideals P^n in the ring of integers O_K of a number field K, it shows you that (O_K/P^n)* is usually not a cyclic group (unless K_P = Q_p for p the prime below P, with p odd or p = 2 in small cases) since (O_K/P^n)* = O_{K_P}*/(1+P^n) --- I am confusing P as prime in O_K and in O_{K_P} here -- and the p-adic log shows you that the P-adic unit group O_{K_P}* is locally near 1 like a copy of (Z_p)^n, where n = [K_P:Q_p], so you're screwed unless n = 1.

Comment: @Harry: Some references : Hasse's Number Theory, Chapter 15, which is cleaned up in Part III of arXiv:0711.3878; see specially Prop. 34.  See also Prop. 5 of arXiv:0711.3879.

Comment: So Matt, are you saying modern number theory is immoral or amoral? (Of course I'm not entirely serious, but I'm curious what you mean about this being one of the appeals of the subject for you: you approve of the lack of dogma for what a proof should be presumably more than proofs perhaps being ultimately unenlightening?)

Comment: Yuri Manin once remarked to me that when a family of theorems remains mysterious after logically correct proofs have been given, it's a sign that the underlying mathematics is very deep. Henri Darmon made a similar comment, saying that certain formulas of number theory are profoundly mysterious to him and that this is what makes the subject so appealing to him. I personally very much hope that some day we understand these theorems in a natural framework and motivated framework and that their present obscurity is a testament to how much we'll learn from understanding them deeply.

Comment: Dear Kevin, Regarding the morality, probably amoral rather than immoral.  I do like the lack of dogma; of course, I also like pure thought and enlightenment as much as the next person. The appeal I spoke of is more one of practicalities than one of principles. I like the fact that theorems don't get proved by pure thought alone: rather, experimentally observed phenomena play an important role, and there is plenty of room for trickery, devious manoeuvres, and also calculation.    The whole thing has a catch-as-catch-can quality, and therein lies the appeal.

Comment: I should probably add (for safety, although it is hopefully clear) that I am speaking on behalf of myself only, not modern number theory as an abstract entity, or any modern number theorists besides myself.

Comment: @JonahSinick: I don't think so. What if it is not at all deep but simply chaotic? There are $Σ_1$-sentences over PA that cannot be proven or disproven unless the foundations of mathematics are inconsistent, so why should we expect random sentences that can be proven to be provable for any good reason? How do we know that the theorems of number theory are not akin to theorems for the busy-beaver function's value on specific inputs? Provable BB values seem not much different from the sporadic finite simple groups.

Comment: In fact, the idea of the BB function gives a proof-theoretic reason to believe that most number theory problems that humans consider are not going to have 'elegant' proofs. Consider the function $PP$ (for prolonged proof) where $PP(n)$ is the minimum upper bound on the shortest proof lengths over all provable sentences of length at most $n$. Since we're talking about number theory, our system certainly can interpret arithmetic, thus $PP$, just like $BB$, eventually exceeds any computable function! Probably $PP$ grows very fast too, so elegance of a theorem does not guarantee an elegant proof!

Answer (score 21):

I am by no means the expert on algebraic geometry. But maybe I can say a little bit. Kontsevich seems ever wrote a book"Beyond Number" There is one paragraph:

“Very often a mathematician considers his colleague from a different domain with disdain -- what kind of a perverse joy can this guy find in his unmotivated and plainly boring subject? I have tried to learn the hidden beauty in various things, but still for many areas the source of interest is for me a complete mystery.

My theory is that too often people project their human weakness/properties onto their mathematical activity.

There are obvious examples on the surface: for instance, the idea of a classification of some objects is an incarnation of collector instincts, the search for maximal values is another form of greed, computability/decidability comes from the desire of a total control.

Fascination with iterations is similar to the hypnotism of rhythmic music. Of course, the classification of some kinds of objects could be very useful in the analysis of more complicated structures, or it could just be memorized in simple cases.

The knowledge of the exact maximum or an upper bound of some quantity depending on parameters gives an idea about the range of its possible values. A theoretical computability can be in fact practical for computer experiments. **Still, for me the motivation is mostly the desire to understand the hidden machinery in a striking concrete example, around which one can build formalisms.**

..... In a deep sense we are all geometers."

I think what Kontsevich mean is that not only the result should be correct, but also the method to get the result should be elegant and natural. Just as he mentioned, the most interesting things to him is the hidden machinery behind the striking examples. For example, say Atiyah-Singer index theorem. Rosenberg ever mentioned in the class, this theorem should have the machinery living in the abelian categories or even exact categories instead of triangulated categories(where Grothendieck Riemman Roch is now living). I guess what they are thinking about is that one should use some **universal constructions** ,universal theory"(in some sense). They always make emphasis on one sentence **"Mathematics should be simple"** which might means that the proof of some big theorem should be simple. That is to say, one does not pay much "brain thinking" because "brain of human are weak"

However, I agree with Emerton that this is very personal feelings

Comment: Can you give a reference for the quote?

Comment: Found it ("The Unravelers: Mathematical Snapshots" edited by Jean-Francois Dars and Annick Lesne)

Comment: In a deep sense we are all geometers!

Answer (score 9):

Presumably, Kontsevich is referencing the fact that Deligne used a "trick" to prove the Weil conjectures.  Kontsevich is presumably talking about the Grothendieck standard conjectures on algebraic cycles, which would allow us to "realize the dream of motives".

I see no way to "moralize" Deligne's proof, because as I said, it relies on a "trick" which circumvents the hard parts of the standard conjectures.

Comment: =P Can't vote me down anymore.  Oh well.  It's quite funny that my answer was essentially the same as Emerton's, and it was posted first.  I included fewer details, but that doesn't mean my answer deserves a vote down.

Comment: Dear Harry: This koan, from the Jargon File, is one of my favorites. "A novice was trying to fix a broken Lisp machine by turning the power off and on. Knight, seeing what the student was doing, spoke sternly: "You cannot fix a machine by just power-cycling it with no understanding of what is going wrong." Knight turned the machine off and on. The machine worked."

Answer (score 7):

This is both an answer and a question:

As part of a response to a previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3430/castelnuovo-positivity-rewrite-of-weils-original-proof-for-fp2) of mine, David Speyer wrote that:

> ... it is known how to adapt Weil's proof of the Riemann hypothesis to higher dimensional S, if one had an analogue of the Hodge index theorem for $S \times S$ in characteristic p. I've been told that a good reference for this is  [Kleiman's Algebraic Cycles and the Weil Conjectures](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=292838)...

So perhaps a "moral" proof would require a Hodge index theorem in characteristic p.

However, David later writes that Grothendieck's standard conjectures assert that the Hodge  theorem holds. So is this possible proof the same as "Grothendieck's envisaged" one?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Grothendieck's standard conjectures incorporate certain "positivity" results about cohomology and cup product which suffice to imply RH.  You could look at Serre's letter to Weil, in which he proves a version of RH for endomorphisms of a complex projective variety via Hodge theory, to get a sense of how such things might work.  And then Kleiman's article gives the details, I believe.